# How to create a video from Flutter camera image stream?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutters `camera` package and `startImageStream` method

I get every couple of ms one image to process inside processCameraImage method and this is working fine so far.

`_controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);`

I want to create a video out of these images and upload it on my server.

Is there any way to merge these single images into for instance mp4 or whatever video format and then upload the file to the backend